# Find polynomials $u(x), v(x)$ satisfying $X^5 + X^2 = (X^3 + X + 1)u(x) + v(x)$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I'm not absolutely sure if I'm answering this correctly but here is the question.

Let $F=GF(2)$. find polynomials $u(x), v(x) \in F[X]$ satisfying $X^5 + X^2 = (X^3 + X + 1)u(x) + v(x)$

What I think is if $u(x)= x^2$, then $(X^3 + X +1)\cdot X^2 = X^5 + X^3 + X^2$, therefore $v(x)=-X^3$

Answer (score 4):

Just perform division algorithm (long division). $u(x)$ is your quotient and $v(x)$ can be your remainder. I don't think the question is looking for any $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ because if that is the case you can always choose $u(x)=0$ and $v(x)$ as the given polynomial.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying tha u(x)=x^2 -1  and v(x)=(x+1)/(x^3+x+1) then?

Comment: Your $u(x)$ is correct but $v(x)=x+1$ not $(x+1)/x^3+x+1$.